# Left joins in table 2

Tags: sql, join, rank

I am trying to do 3 things here

1. Merge users from table 1 into table 2 query but I keep getting errors (doesn't seem to like the users =)
2. I am trying to make sure the eventTimeStamp in t2 happens after iap table (this also doesn't seem to like the iap.eventTimeStamp). Assume because there is no join working at the moment.
3. The final table to count the eventname in order from table 2 so I can cap the first event only
   Can anyone help me please, I have tried a few different methods and no luck!

```
with iap as (
select min(eventTimeStamp) as firstPurchase, userID, productID
from xx
group by 2,3
),

t2 as (
select eventTimestamp, userID as users, eventname
from xx
left join iap on users=iap.userID
where eventname in (xx, xx, xx)
and eventTimeStamp > iap.firstPurchase
)

select productID as IAP, eventname, count(distinct iap.userid) as users, dense_rank() over(partition by userID order by eventTimeStamp) as inGameIAP
from iap
--where t2.eventTimeStamp > iap.eventTimeStamp
where inGameIAP=1
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Can you add the error(s) you're getting?

Comment: `left join iap on users=iap.userID`? When you have a join, please prepend each column with the table name or its alias (talking about `users` here) so it becomes clear which table each column comes from. It may be obvious to you but not for us. By the way, you can't use a column alias just created in a `JOIN` clause; use the bona fide column name.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I originally had t2.userid but had the same error. This is the current issue I am getting now - "invalid identifier 'USERS'", the same error if I add the alias and have left join iap on t2.userid = iap.userid (invalid identifier 'T2.USERID')

Comment: you mention to use the bona fide column name then I get this error: SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'USERID' on (left join iap on userid = iap.userID)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: this pretty much is the exact code, but I have only taken out a few where statements which are not really relevant. I just can't run the code because of the second join in table 2 - it doesn't seem to recognise users. How can I define t2? Thanks for the tips